# How can I query the local network for the current datetime via SNTP?

Tags: c#, datetime

We're getting ready to roll out a beta of one of our new products, and since we haven't put in the licensing component yet we decided we would just put in a time bomb so the beta version won't work after a certain date. Obviously we don't want to just trust the system time, since that's easy to roll back.

We already have checks to a couple different NTP servers on the Internet as well as some checks for the time in the headers of HTTP responses from some major websites, but our software is intended for use in an industry where it's not unheard of to have a secure local network with no Internet access. Therefore we figured it would be nice to get a date from the local network's time server (if it has one) via SNTP (or NTP, if that's easier).

We just need a simple query, though, and all the C# SNTP examples I've seen online are full-featured clients capable of keeping a machine's system time synched and acting as a local NTP server at any stratum you want to configure them for, which is complete overkill for our needs.

Can anyone explain how to do a broadcast query like this? The NTP query code we have require a specific address to connect to, which obviously we won't know for customers' local networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remembered this question, figured I'd post the solution I found:

```
var cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        Arguments = "/C net time /DOMAIN:" + Environment.UserDomainName,
        UseShellExecute = false
    }
};

cmd.Start();

string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
if (output.EndsWith("The command completed successfully.\r\n\r\n"))
{
    int is_index = output.IndexOf("is ");
    int serv_start = output.IndexOf(@"\\") + 2;
    int serv_end = is_index - 1;
    string time_server = output.Substring(serv_start, serv_end - serv_start).Split(new char[] { '.' })[0];
    if (time_server == Environment.MachineName)
        return DateTime.MaxValue; // local machine is acting as time server

    int time_start = is_index + 3;
    int time_end = output.IndexOf("\r");
    string local = output.Substring(time_start, time_end - time_start);
    return DateTime.ParseExact(local, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

return DateTime.MaxValue;
```

This gets the current time from the domain's time server; it will return DateTime.MaxValue if the command fails or if the local machine is the time server (if you trust the system time, why are you checking the local network?). Exception handling has been omitted for brevity.

I did *not* investigate what culture `net time` uses to format its output, so it may be necessary to use something other than InvariantCulture for that.